# How to Open a Very Large Image in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing

Is there a way to read a huge bmp file?

it size (x-101379,y-255286) and 24.1GB

I want to cut the file into a go board format. (Baduk board)

can I?

Comment: i have 64GB RAM

Comment: You should take a look at Zarr (https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). It allows you to access memory in the disk and compress it.

Comment: Look at `pyvips`.